# How to apply inverse perspective mapping for a bird's eye view case using rotation and translation in python

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, homography

I'm working with a monocular camera in real-time, and I'm trying to recover a bird's eye view to detect the distance between humans. I'm using OpenCV libraries in python and I used the function warpPerspective to get the transformed image.

In other words,  Im asking how to get top-down view from camera view (using just computer' webcam) for measuring real world distances in the picture (just on surface). What i know or have: camera picture resolution (vertical, horizontal) height of camera I know, everything is about using next methods: warpPerspective(), getPerpectiveTransform, or similarly with affine transform. But I really don't know how to correctly use it.

Comment: there are samples in opencv for apply inverse perspective. please consider ask a specific question, because we don't know 1 what you know, 2 what you don't know. .

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the **tour** (https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read the information guides in the **help center** (https://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular, "How to Ask A Good Question" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), "What Are Good Topics" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and "How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example" (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @DrYuanShenghai  

Im asking how to get top-down view from camera view (using just computer' webcam) for measuring real world distances in the picture (just on surface). What i know or have:

camera picture resolution (vertical, horizontal) height of camera I know, everything is about using next methods: warpPerspective(), getPerpectiveTransform, or similarly with affine transform.

But I really don't know how to correctly use it.

Thanks in advance doctor